# Titanium SDK gives a "file too short" error

Tags: 11.04, development

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and recently installed Appcelerator Titanium Studio version 1.7 When I load up a demo project to run, I get an error like this,

> Couldn't load file:/home/dananjaya/.titanium/runtime/linux/1.1.0/libkhost.so, error: /home/dananjaya/.titanium/runtime/linux/1.1.0/libwebkittitanium-1.0.so.2: file too short

Am I missing some dependencies here or is it a bug in the application? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This is beta software according to [their website](http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/) and was released on the 13th:

"The Titanium SDK 1.7 Release Candidate 1 may have undesirable bugs and regressions and partial features, and is not recommended for production use."

The file is inside your installation of titanium and the error message to me sounds like a problem with that software and looks like it is not from missing something in Ubuntu.

Best practice would be to file a bug on the [bug website](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD).

The desktop version is 1.2.0-rc1 (1.7 is the mobile version) and it states in the [release notes](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/desktop/release_notes):

"Linux requires a current up to date Maverick 10.10, Natty (11.04) is not supported."

You might be out of luck with getting this to work on Natty...

Comment: I've run into this today on a 32 bit version shipped with TideSDK. libwebkittitanium-1.0.so.2 is one byte long.